# How to authorize one solr user to one core for solr 7

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solrnet

**I want to create multiple user each user can access one or multiple core, I have two cores [Solr_sample and name core]I tried to create the below file, but it didn't work**

```
   "authentication":{
      "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
      "blockUnknown": true,
      "credentials":{
         "solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c=",
         "devuser":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="
      }
   },
   "authorization":{
      "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
     
      "permissions":[
       {
            "name":"core-admin-read",
            "path": "/admin/cores/Solr_sample/select?q=*:*",
            "role":"admin"
         }
         
      ],
       "user-role":{
         "solr":"admin",
         "devuser":"dev"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? The `select` path isn't under the `/admin` namespace - so if you're trying to limit who can select from the core, there are other permissions you're looking for: `For APIs accessing collections, path values should start after the collection name, and often just look like the request handler (e.g., "/select").`

Comment: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/rule-based-authorization-plugin.html#custom-permissions

Comment: I mean that the access is allowed to all users even if I write role : admin

Comment: I want for example to let user dev see sample core and user admin see all cores

Comment: You'll need a permission matching the collection `*` with role: "admin" (so that only admin users can read from collections), and then another rule for that specific collection with role: "dev".

Comment: `{
            "name":"core-admin-read",
            "path": "/select",
            "role":"admin"
         },
    {
            "name":"collection-admin-read",
            "collection": "*",
            "role":"admin"
         }
           ,
    {
            "name":"collection-admin-read",
            "collection": "Solr_sample",
            "role":"dev"
         }` , I tried this but still dev user can see all cores @MatsLindh

Comment: If you're trying to limit whether they can _list_ the cores, that's a different endpoint - that might require a specific rule for a `/admin/...` endpoint (check the network tab in your browser's developer tool to see where the request is being made). Your first rule doesn't make sense either, since it doesn't mention any collection; you might also need path: * for your second and third rule to indicate you want those to apply to any path under the collection handler.